# Suggest me which version ubuntu is to download for my system configuration

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, 13.04, system-requirements

I want to buy a netbook with the following configuration. Its comes with free DOS, so i want to install ubntu on this (as ubuntu requires less system configuration compared to windows). I am newbie here give me suggestion about which version should i download and can i go for 32-bit or 64-bit.Please suggest me the best one which is suitable for the below configuration. My requirements is browsing internet and it not hang in middle.

PROCESSOR

Processor -Celeron Dual Core Variant 847

Chipset - Mobile HM70 Express

Brand - Intel

Clock Speed - 1.1 GHz

Cache - 2 MB

MEMORY

System Memory - 2GB DDR3

STORAGE

Hardware Interface - SATA

RPM -  5400

HDD Capacity - 320 GB

PLATFORM

Operating System - Free DOS

System Architecture - 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

You can go for the latest version 13.10 . It will work fine.
Latest system requirements for 13.10 are

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
(Internet access is helpful)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you run **Ubuntu** *12.04.3 LTS, 32-bit*. *You have a slower hard drive,  only 2GB RAM, and an older processor. You will also be limited by graphic processor performance.*

---

***LATER***

With that as a benchmark, you can then see if a **LiveCD** trial of **Ubuntu** *13.10 64-bit* is any improvement.